# Return Value Based on Two Conditions: one condition determines which table to look at the other, which value to return

Tags: python, pandas

The Set-Up:

I have 3 dataframes:

```
data = {'w_s': ['w','s','w', 's'],
        'date': ['01/17/2023', '03/05/2023','02/04/2023','03/30/2023']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2 = {'begin_date': ['01/01/2023', '01/15/2023', '01/29/2023'],
         'end_date': ['01/14/2023', '01/28/2023','02/12/2023'],
         'week_num': [1, 2, 3]}

df_w = pd.DataFrame(data2)

data3 = {'begin_date': ['03/01/2023', '03/15/2023', '03/29/2023'],
         'end_date': ['03/14/2023', '03/28/2023','04/12/2023'],
         'week_num': [7, 8, 9]}

df_s = pd.DataFrame(data3)
```

which look like this:

```
df1
  w_s        date
0   w  01/17/2023
1   s  03/05/2023
2   w  02/04/2023
3   s  03/30/2023

df_s
begin_date    end_date  week_num
0  03/01/2023  03/14/2023         7
1  03/15/2023  03/28/2023         8
2  03/29/2023  04/12/2023         9

df_w
   begin_date    end_date  week_num
0  01/01/2023  01/14/2023         1
1  01/15/2023  01/28/2023         2
2  01/29/2023  02/12/2023         3
```

The Problem:

In df1, IF w_s = 'w', THEN return the `week_num` value in the df_w dataframe, WHERE the `date` (in df1) falls between the `begin_date` and the `end_date` (in df_w)

Conversely, IF w_s = 's', THEN return the `week_num` value in the df_s dataframe, WHERE the `date` (in df1) falls between the `begin_date` and the `end_date` (in df_s).

I need to look at which dataframe to reference first: df_w or df_s based on the w_s column. Then I need to find the row in which the df1['date'] falls in between the begin and end date in either the df_s or df_w dataframe.

The desired output:

```
0   w  01/17/2023         2
1   s  03/05/2023         7
2   w  02/04/2023         3
3   s  03/30/2023         9
```

I feel like this is going to be really simple, but I've been banging my head on a brick wall...

TIA for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pd.merge` to merge first on `w_s` column then keep only rows where `begin_date <= date <= end_date`:

```
out = (df1.merge(pd.concat([df_w.assign(w_s='w'),
                            df_s.assign(w_s='s')]),
                 on='w_s', how='left')
          .query('(begin_date <= date) & (date <= end_date)'))
print(out)

# Output
   w_s        date  begin_date    end_date  week_num
1    w  01/17/2023  01/15/2023  01/28/2023         2
3    s  03/05/2023  03/01/2023  03/14/2023         7
8    w  02/04/2023  01/29/2023  02/12/2023         3
11   s  03/30/2023  03/29/2023  04/12/2023         9
```

In my code, I suppose your columns are `datetime64` ready. If not, use:

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df_w['begin_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_w['begin_date'])
df_w['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_w['end_date'])
df_s['begin_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_s['begin_date'])
df_s['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_s['end_date'])
```

Comment: woww..It was a clean functional approach @Corralien !!!!!!!

Comment: *facepalm* merge. I was trying to use an overly complicated np.where...

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
# ensure we have datetime types
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df_w[['begin_date', 'end_date']] = df_w[['begin_date', 'end_date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df_s[['begin_date', 'end_date']] = df_s[['begin_date', 'end_date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# concat the query DataFrames (there could be more than 2)
df2 = (pd.concat({'s': df_s, 'w': df_w}).rename_axis(('w_s', None))
         .reset_index('w_s').sort_values(by='begin_date')
      )

# merge and restore original order
out = pd.merge_asof(
    df1.reset_index().sort_values(by='date'),
    df2, by='w_s',
    left_on='date', right_on='begin_date',
).set_index('index').sort_index()
```

Output:

```
      w_s       date begin_date   end_date  week_num
index                                               
0       w 2023-01-17 2023-01-15 2023-01-28         2
1       s 2023-03-05 2023-03-01 2023-03-14         7
2       w 2023-02-04 2023-01-29 2023-02-12         3
3       s 2023-03-30 2023-03-29 2023-04-12         9
```